# Audio icon in FIFA 12 match?

Tags: fifa-12

Today I played a guy who intentionally created an audio icon on the top right of the screen in match to distract my view. Anyone know what it is and how to turn it off ? It's really annoying.

Comment: What platform was this on? How big was the icon and did it have any text next to it? Was it a voice communication icon?

Comment: @AnthonyBlake, yes, it maybe a voice communication icon. The platform is Windows 7. Is there a way to turn it off ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible, but as you can see from the following link, it has been received as a suggestion by developers for a future patch/release.

> Thanks for bringing this to our attention. We'll be sure to pass it
>   along to the developers for consideration

http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/7736907.page